# OpenGL VertexBuffer Class redefinition and template method errors

Tags: c++, oop

I have a simple OpenGL program that draws a square with a draw pipeline following these steps: using OpenGL I bind my shader > bind my vertex array > bind my index buffer with my list of points for 2 triangles > draw the triangle data to my window using the vertex and shader data I've bound to my program. I'm using OpenGL version 3.3.0 on NVIDIA GPU version 388.13 with GLEW version 2.1.0.

The abstractions I've created for this draw pipeline are now throwing some errors. This pipeline and code worked before I introudced . Notably in the template push method I have in my `VertexBufferLayout` class.

```
template<class T>
void VertexBufferLayout::push(unsigned int elements_per_vertex);
```

As well as 'class' or 'struct' type redefinition errors for `VertexBuffer`, `VertexBufferLayout`, and `VertexBufferLayoutElement`. I wonder if this is an issue with my constructors for each of these?

**VertexBuffer 
header**

```
class VertexBuffer
{
private:
    unsigned int m_renderer_id;
public:
    VertexBuffer(const void* data, unsigned int size);
    ~VertexBuffer();

    void bind() const;
    void unbind() const;
};
```

**cpp**

```
#include "VertexBuffer.h"

VertexBuffer::VertexBuffer(const void* data, unsigned int size)
{
    MyGLCall(glGenBuffers(1, &m_renderer_id));
    MyGLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_renderer_id));
    MyGLCall(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW));
}
```

**VertexBufferLayout header** which also contains my **VertexBufferLayoutElement** struct

```
#include <vector>

#include <GL\glew.h>

#include "Renderer.h"

struct VertexBufferLayoutElement
{
    // nice mem alignment bro, mem size on most machines is
    unsigned int elements_per_vertex;   // 4 bytes
    unsigned int type;                  // 4 bytes
    unsigned char normalized;           // 1 byte
    static unsigned int get_size_of_type(unsigned int type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case GL_FLOAT:          return 4;
            case GL_UNSIGNED_INT:   return 4;
            case GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE:  return 1;
        }
        ASSERT(false);
        return 0;
    }
};

class VertexBufferLayout
{
private:
    unsigned int m_stride; // vertex_mem_address_width
    std::vector<VertexBufferLayoutElement> m_elements;
public:
    VertexBufferLayout();
    ~VertexBufferLayout();

    template<class T>
    void push(unsigned int elements_per_vertex);
    // these 3 templates MUST use the format above
    template<>
    void push<float>(unsigned int elements_per_vertex);
    template<>
    void push<unsigned int>(unsigned int elements_per_vertex);
    template<>
    void push<unsigned char>(unsigned int elements_per_vertex);

    // need const& here?
    inline const std::vector<VertexBufferLayoutElement> get_elements() const { return m_elements; }
    inline unsigned int get_stride() const { return m_stride; }
};
```

**cpp**

```
#include "VertexBufferLayout.h"

VertexBufferLayout::VertexBufferLayout() 
    : m_stride(0) { }
```

I will temporal leave all the source .h and .cpp files in [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/deslzk5gm664doy/AADFpVei7LlHPFHGchSSgxuWa?dl=0) to help with feedback. I'll delete them once I have an answer.

**Full 1 warning and 8 error details below.**

```
Warning C4067    unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline    BasicOOP    D:\opengl\BasicOOP\BasicOOP\VertexArray.h   1   
Error   C2062    type 'float' unexpected    BasicOOP    D:\opengl\BasicOOP\BasicOOP\Main.cpp    67  
Error   C2664    'void VertexArray::add_buffer(const VertexBuffer &,const VertexBufferLayout &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const VertexBuffer &'    BasicOOP    D:\opengl\BasicOOP\BasicOOP\Main.cpp    68  
Error   C2011    'VertexBufferLayoutElement': 'struct' type redefinition    BasicOOP    D:\opengl\BasicOOP\BasicOOP\VertexBufferLayout.h    8   
Error   C2011    'VertexBufferLayout': 'class' type redefinition    BasicOOP    D:\opengl\BasicOOP\BasicOOP\VertexBufferLayout.h    27  
Error   C2079    'vertexBufferLayout' uses undefined class 'VertexBufferLayout' BasicOOP    D:\opengl\BasicOOP\BasicOOP\Main.cpp    66  
Error   C2011    'VertexBuffer': 'class' type redefinition  BasicOOP    D:\opengl\BasicOOP\BasicOOP\VertexBuffer.h  2   
Error   C2079    'vertexBuffer' uses undefined class 'VertexBuffer' BasicOOP    D:\opengl\BasicOOP\BasicOOP\Main.cpp    64  
Error   C2440    'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'int'    BasicOOP    D:\opengl\BasicOOP\BasicOOP\Main.cpp    64
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Renderer.h"

#include "VertexArray.h"
#include "VertexBuffer.h"
#include "VertexBufferLayout.h"
#include "IndexBuffer.h"
#include "ShaderManager.h"

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Object Oriented OpenGL\n";

    GLFWwindow* window;
    if (!glfwInit()) { return -1; }
    // opengl v3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Object Oriented OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(3);

    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()) { std::cout << "ERROR initializing OpenGL GLEW\n"; }

    std::cout << "Rendering...\nOpenGL version " << glGetString(GL_VERSION)
        << "\nGL Extension Wrangler version " << glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION);

    // big scope why?
    // both buffers are stack allocated, destructor called when scope exits
    // odd use case we have here... rare to make buffers in main function scope 
    // This creates infinite loop on glfwTerminate(), we call glfwTerminate() BEFORE exiting main scope
    // and having both Buffers destructors clean them up
    // could make these pointers and heap allocate these with new, but let's just change where scope of these are defined
    /*
        VertexBuffer vertexBuffer(tri_verticies, buffer_object_size * sizeof(float));
        IndexBuffer indexBuffer(tri_indicies, index_buffer_object_size);
    */
    {
        const int buffer_object_size = 8;
        const int index_buffer_object_size = 6;
        float tri_verticies[buffer_object_size] = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f, // 0
             0.5f, -0.5f, // 1
             0.5f,  0.5f, // 2
            -0.5f,  0.5f  // 3
        };
        unsigned int tri_indicies[index_buffer_object_size] = {
            0, 1, 2,
            2, 3, 0
        };

        // both buffers are stack allocated, destructor called when scope exits
        // odd use case we have here... rare to make buffers in main function scope 
        // could heap allocate these with new, but let's just change where scope of these are defined
        VertexArray vertexArray;                
        VertexBuffer vertexBuffer(tri_verticies, buffer_object_size * sizeof(float)); // no call vertexBuffer.bind() constructor does it    

        VertexBufferLayout vertexBufferLayout;
        vertexBufferLayout.push<float>(2);
        vertexArray.add_buffer(vertexBuffer, vertexBufferLayout);

        IndexBuffer indexBuffer(tri_indicies, index_buffer_object_size);        

        ShaderManager shaderManager;
        ShaderSource shaderSource = shaderManager.parse_shader("BasicUniform.shader");  // ensure debug working dir is relative to $(ProjectDir)
        unsigned int shader = shaderManager.create_shader(shaderSource.vertex_source, shaderSource.fragment_source);
        MyGLCall(glUseProgram(shader));

        // every uniform has a name as it's id
         MyGLCall(int location = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "u_color"));
         ASSERT(location != -1);
         MyGLCall(glUniform4f(location, 0.5f, 0.2f, 0.7f, 1.0f));

        // * * * * * * * * * * * *
        // first unbind everything
        // * * * * * * * * * * * *
        // http://docs.gl/gl4/glBindBuffer
        /*
        `   Buffer object names are unsigned integers.The value zero is reserved, but there is no default buffer object for each buffer object target.Instead, buffer set to zero effectively unbinds any buffer object previously bound, and restores client memory usage for that buffer object target(if supported for that target).
        */
        vertexArray.unbind();
        MyGLCall(glUseProgram(0)); // was shader
        MyGLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)); // was buffer_object
        MyGLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)); // was index_buffer_object

        float blue = 0.7f;
        float increment = 0.05f;

        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        {
            MyGLCall(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT));
            // * * * * * * * * * * * * *
            // then bind everything back
            // * * * * * * * * * * * * *
            // 1. bind shader and setup uniform
            MyGLCall(glUseProgram(shader));
            MyGLCall(glUniform4f(location, 0.5f, 0.2f, blue, 1.0f));
            // 2. bind index buffer
            // all replaced with the next line that links vertex buffer to vertex array object
            vertexArray.bind();
            indexBuffer.bind();

            // use below for index buffer
            // triple AAA games use me :) the right way to draw triple AAA mario is below
            // want to draw mario? one vertex buffer for all his vertex data, then many index buffers to draw each pieces of the model
            // marios boots will be a different material than his hat
            MyGLCall(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, index_buffer_object_size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr)); // nullptr since we bind buffers using glGenBuffers

            if (blue > 1.0f) {
                increment = -0.05f;
            }
            else if (blue < 0.0f) {
                increment = 0.05f;
            }

            blue += increment;

            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();
        }

        MyGLCall(glDeleteProgram(shader));
    }

    //while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    //{
    //  /* Render here */
    //  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //  /* Swap front and back buffers */
    //  glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    //  /* Poll for and process events */
    //  glfwPollEvents();
    //}

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, it's because you haven't added

```cpp
#pragma once
```

to the start of your header files (and so the same header is being included multiple times, redefining your class type)

/edit

If you have some header file, for example

```cpp
// foo.h
class Foo { };
```

And we then end up including it twice in the same file, e.g.

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include "foo.h"  //< usually due to another file including foo.h
```

We'll end up with:

```cpp
class Foo { };
class Foo { };  ///< compiler error! redefined class Foo
```

To prevent the file being included a second time, just do:

```cpp
#pragma once

class Foo { };
```

And now the file will only ever be included once.

Comment: I'll try when I'm back on my computer. Why is   is this pragma macro required?

Comment: It's technically a non-standard pre-processor directive (which happens to be supported on all major C++ compilers). I've added more details above.

Comment: Thanks that's very clear. I accomplish this header file guards as well right? To make sure my class definitions aren't included twice.

Comment: You can do yes, but #pragma once is a better solution imho.